# How can I open File Manager at specific directory from notification?

Tags: android, file, android-notifications, file-manager

I want to open a specific directory in File Manager on notification click.
Unfortunately, I got stuck on the part when only the default directory is opening, in my case, it is the Download catalogue.
First I created an Intent in the following way:

```
val path = "/storage/emulated/0/Android/media/${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}/MyApp/archives"
val uri = Uri.parse(path)
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri)
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "*/*")
```

Then I created a pending intent:
`val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0)`

And pass it to the Notification builder:

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
   .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
   .setContentTitle(contentTitle)
   .setContentText(contentText)
   .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
   .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
   .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
   .setStyle(NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle())
   .setOngoing(false)
   .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```

I also tried a solution with FileProvider. First I created XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
   <external-media-path name="external_paths" path="." />
</paths>
```

And creating intent like:

```
val dir = File(path)
val selectedUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"${BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID}.fileprovider" , dir)

val intent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
    addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
    setDataAndType(selectedUri, "*/*")
}
```

I added also a provider in the Android manifest:

```
<provider
   android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
   android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
   android:exported="false"
   android:grantUriPermissions="true">
   <meta-data
       android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
       android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

The same result for file providers too.
Is there any option to open a different directory than Downloads?

Comment: "I want to open a specific directory in File Manager" -- sorry, but there has never been a standard Android `Intent` structure for that.

Comment: @CommonsWare I see, thank you.

Comment: What is it what you wanna let the user do?  Pick a file? Pick a directory? Just browse? Needed for Android version..?

Comment: @blackapps My case is only to show where files are placed, so just browse. minSdkVersion: 26.